# Retrieving a specific value from “df -h” using shell

Tags: shell

When I use df -h, I get the following output:

> Filesystem            Size  Used Avail
>   Use% Mounted on
>
> /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
>                          59G  2.2G   54G   4% /
>
> /dev/sda1             122M   38M   78M
>   33% /boot
>
> tmpfs                 1.1G     0  1.1G
>   0% /dev/shm
>
> 10.10.0.105:/somepath
>
> ```
>                    11T  8.4T  2.1T  81% /storage4
> ```
>
> 10.11.0.101:/somepath
>
> ```
>                    15T  8.9T  5.9T  61% /storage1
> ```
>
> /dev/mapper/patha    5.0T  255G  4.8T
>   5% /storage5_vol0
>
> /dev/mapper/pathb    5.0T  195G  4.9T
>   4% /storage5_vol1
>
> /dev/mapper/pathc    5.0T  608G  4.5T
>   12% /storage5_vol2

I want to write a script that gets the value of ***Avail*** column on a specific storage.

I used to use

> df -k /storage_name | tail -1 | awk
>   '{print $3}'

But the ***FileSystem*** column can have a value or not .. which would change the variable of my script from $3 to $4.

How can I get the ***Avail*** on a single command line even if there are no values on the previous columns?

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://superuser.com/questions/257915/retrieving-a-specific-value-from-df-h-using-shell).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use df's -P option for "portability" or "POSIX" output and change to the 4th field for the available count.

`df -kP /storage_name | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}'`